# Optimal memory for page loading in hosted environment?

Tags: php, optimization, server, hosting

In PHP, shared hosting environment, what shall be an optimal memory consumption to load a page. My current PHP script is consuming 3,183,440 bytes of memory. What shall I consider a good memory usage, to entertain say, 10000 users parallely?

Please be detailed, as I am a novice in optimization part.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3MB isn't that bad - keep in mind that parts of PHP are shared, depending on which server is used (IIS, ngx, apache etc.) you can specify pools and clusters as well when having to scale up.

But the old adage testing is knowledge goes well here, try load tests on the site, concurrent 10 -> 100 -> 1000 connections and look at the performance metrics, it wil give you more insight on how much memory is required.

For comparison, the site I normally work on has an average of 300+ users concurrently online and the memory usage is just under 600MB, however I run certain processes locally it will easily use up 16MB.